# WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Reporting Services Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, reporting-services

I want to download a ssrs report and add it to an automated email as pdf attachment, when i paste the download link in the browser it just downloads the file but when i try it with my application i get an: `WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Reporting Services Error.` error.

This is my current code that i use to download the bytes from the URL and set add them to the email as an attachment

```cs
                WebClient webclient = new WebClient();

                CredentialCache credentialsCache = new CredentialCache();
                credentialsCache.Add(new Uri(downloadLink), "NTLM", new NetworkCredential("username", "password"));

                webclient.Credentials = credentialsCache;

                byte[] bytes = webclient.DownloadData(downloadLink);
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);

                MailMessage mailmsg = new MailMessage("from@gmail.com", "to@gmail.com", "subject", "Test");
                mailmsg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ms, "temp.pdf"));
                client.Send(mailmsg);
```

i tried downloading the file directly as a pdf but i get the same error and i cant find any way to fix it so hopefully some extra eyes can solve the problem.

this is the error:

````
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBits(WebRequest request, Stream writeStream)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(Uri address)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(String address)
   at Mail.Pages.PrivacyModel.btn_SendMessage_Click() in C:\Projects\Reporting Connector\Connector\Mail\Pages\Privacy.cshtml.cs:line 149
   at Mail.Pages.PrivacyModel.OnPostWork1() in C:\Projects\Reporting Connector\Connector\Mail\Pages\Privacy.cshtml.cs:line 42
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory.VoidHandlerMethod.Execute(Object receiver, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeHandlerMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeNextPageFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Rethrow(PageHandlerExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)```
````

Comment: In doubt, `new NetworkCredential("username", "password")` is the real code? Or the user's name and password is set?

Comment: @Vernou yeah that isn't the real code i changed it for safety reasons